# Physics Body for SKLabelNode in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skphysicsbody

How do I create a Physics Body for a string of characters in SpriteKit?
I don't want it to be a rectangle around the font, I want each letter to be its own shape for contact.

Comment: It looks complicated. But first think i would try would be trying. 
(+ bodyWithTexture:size:) 
(+ bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:)
You can give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a built in way to create an `SKPhysicsBody` from a `SKLabelNode` or characters in a string.

You might want to look into creating a full image set of alphabetic characters, creating an `SKImageNode` for each letter in a string, and using `+ bodyWithTexture: size:` to assign each a body based on its texture.